# How to remove form elements from PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

I'm looking for a way to convert PDF documents that our clients will be uploading to our Java backend server, to a "simpler" form, so they can later be rendered correctly in the iPad app. I'm not an expert in PDF, but as far as I can tell, I need to remove interactive form elements and/or convert PDF to PDF-X version.

I looked into iText's "setPDFXConformance(PdfWriter.PDFXNONE)", but it didn't do much. I'd like to do it with PDFBox, because of it's friendly license,  but I'll take any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it with GhostScript like this:

> gs -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer broken.pdf